# Assigning data from e.Row.DataItem

Tags: asp.net

As i am new to asp i have a small problem regarding assigning based on e.Row.DataItem.
code:

```
protected void grdStaffReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationRegistration appReg = new ApplicationRegistration();

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        All_Ticket allTicket = e.Row.DataItem as All_Ticket;
        if (allTicket != null)
        {
            Label lblTicketId = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTicketId"));
            lblTicketId.Text = "PHDT" + allTicket.TicketId;
            Label lblStartedBy = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStartedBy"));
            lblStartedBy.Text = this.GetTicketStartBy(allTicket.ClientId);
            HyperLink hylnk = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1");
            hylnk.NavigateUrl = "~/User/DisplayTicket.aspx?TicketId=" + allTicket.TicketId + " &AppId=" + allTicket.AppId;
            Label lblIsCloesed = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblIsCloesed"));
            if (allTicket.isClosed == true)
            {
                hylnk.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                lblIsCloesed.Text = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                lblIsCloesed.Text = "No";
                hylnk.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
            Label lblLastUpdateBy = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLastUpdateBy"));
            lblLastUpdateBy.Text = this.GetTicketLastUpdateBy(allTicket.TicketId, lblStartedBy.Text);
            TicketRegistration ticReg = new TicketRegistration();
            Ticket_Reply tic = ticReg.GetMaxTicketByTicketId(allTicket.TicketId);
            Label lblUpdationDt = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblUpdationDt");
            Label lblclient = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblClint");
            var user = userManage.GetClientUserByUserId(allTicket.ClientId);
            lblclient.Text = _clientReg.GetClientNameByID(user.ParentId);
            if (tic != null)
            {
                lblUpdationDt.Text = Convert.ToString(tic.CreationDt);
            }
            else
            {
                lblUpdationDt.Text = Convert.ToString(allTicket.CreationDt);
            }

            Label lblAppId = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblApplicaton"));
            lblAppId.Text = appReg.GetAppNameByID(allTicket.AppId);

            Label lblSNo = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSno"));
            lblSNo.Text = (++i).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Here e.Row.DataItem has data(seen by placing breakpoint),but when this is executed allTicket is not assigned any data.

please revert the solution

Comment: Are your sure that the data stored in `e.Row.DataItem` is of type `All_Ticket`?

Comment: how can i know the data is of All_ticket type

Comment: e.Row.DataItem contains data like ticketid,appname,appid,etc..

Comment: It's been a while since I've used ASP.NET, but I think if you put a breakpoint on this line of `All_Ticket allTicket = e.Row.DataItem as All_Ticket`, hover the mouse over `.DataItem` and it might tell you what the type is. Can't recall now if that will work, but try it, at least we can eliminate it as an option.

Comment: yes the data in .dataitem is same type of All_Ticket

Comment: Weird. In that case, I can't see why that line of code to cast `.DataItem` as `All_Ticket` is returning `NULL`.